# Why is my dictionary duplicating a key but not the value?

Tags: python

I'm starting to tinker in Python, and to do that I've been doing (super easy) challenges from /r/DailyProgrammer. I just started working on [#186 easy](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/2kwfqr/10312014_challenge_186_special_code_or_treat/) with [this](https://gist.github.com/coderd00d/54215798871d0c356cfb) as the input, and right now I am at the point of just simply counting the pieces of candy. This is my code so far:

```
myInput = open("C:/users/jacob/desktop/python/186/candy.txt").readlines()
candyDict = dict()
for line in myInput:
    if line not in candyDict:
        candyDict[line] = 0
    if line in candyDict:
        candyDict[line] += 1

for item in candyDict.keys():
    print(str(candyDict[item]) + " : " + item.replace('\n', ""))
```

And this is my output:

```
44 : Skittles
62 : Rock
45 : Jolly Rancher
41 : Snickers
41 : Runts
36 : Almond Joy
39 : Candy Corn
46 : Popcorn
48 : Peppermint Candy
50 : Tootsie Roll
41 : Nerds
44 : Bubblegum
46 : Lollipop
46 : Sweet Tarts
47 : M&Ms
50 : Crunch Bar
67 : Kit Kat
53 : Lifesavers
48 : Tangy Taffy
57 : Peanut Butter Cup
48 : Smarties
1 : M&Ms
```

Why is there an extra `M&Ms` appended to the end of the file? I *think* it is because `M&Ms` is also the last line of the file, but that doesn't explain to me why it would duplicate like that. Any clue as to why would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does your file end in a newline? I'm guessing perhaps not, which would explain this.

Comment: You don't need the second if condition; after conditionally executing the first block, it'll always be true.

Comment: @APerson Thanks for pointing that out :) and yes, Fatal, it does not end with a newline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lines have a line ending character (`"\n"`) at the end of them, as you noticed when you replaced them for printing. The last line in the file probably does not (it may or may not, but from the description you give it seems it doesn't).

The string `"M&Ms\n"` is not the same as the string `"M&Ms"`.

It's also possible that one of the strings has an extra space at the end.

At the start of your for loop, strip off all the extra spaces and newlines with:

```
for line in myInput:
    line = line.strip()
    # etc
```

Comment: Awesome, that was the problem! I didn't know about the strip function yet, that's a lot nicer than .replace('\n', "")

Comment: `strip` solves the issue, but OP might want to further streamline it by doing `candyDict = collections.Counter(line.strip() for line in  myInput)`

Comment: See the docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods . When your code works, you also want to look up collections.defaultdict, and finally collections.Counter to turn the whole thing into a two liner :-)